# Why is the average of my array incorrect?

Tags: java, arrays

Still getting to grips with java, I've reached the end of my assignment without any hiccups until now.  When I calculate the average of values inside my array I keep getting an incorrect answer. Here's my code for getting the values:

```
public static int [] inputGrades()
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int [] iGrades = new int [10];
        System.out.print("\nInput test scores, enter -1 when you're finished.\n");
        for (int i =0; i<iGrades.length;i++)
        {
            iGrades[i]=kb.nextInt();
            if (iGrades[i] ==-1)
            {
                break;
            }
    }
        return iGrades;
```

Then here's my average method for the array:

```
public static double averageArray (int [] array, int numElements)
    {   
        int iSum= 0;
        double dAverage;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i]>0)
            {
                iSum = iSum + array[i];  
            }    

        }
        dAverage = iSum / array.length;
        System.out.print (dAverage);
        return dAverage;
```

If I were to input say 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -1. The output for the averages I would get in return is 15 as opposed to 30.  Any ideas why? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues at play:

(1) This is integer (i.e. truncating) division:

```
dAverage = iSum / array.length;
```

You want

```
dAverage = iSum / (double)array.length`;
```

(2) `array.length` is always 10 and includes zeroes at the end of the array. Thus, in your example you are actually computing the average of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, which is indeed 15.

You need to record how many numbers the user has actually entered, and divide by that instead.

Better still, use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `int[]`, and you can sidestep this problem entirely.

Comment: I haven't gone over `ArrayList` yet, is there anyway to get rid of the unused slots?

Comment: If you shouldn't be using the List API yet, declare your array "large enough" and treat it like a chunk of allocated memory you have to manage. Declare this as a dependency in your comments. Then, track the number of values you gather separately instead of using the length property.

Comment: @jdv Thanks, i created another variable `iCount`to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at array.length.  It is 10, so `dAverage = iSum / array.length` is dividing by 10, always.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there here's the solution without using arrays and after this I will be posting the solution using ArraysList so you can have an idea how it works :). I hope it can help you

```
    int total = 0;
    int numberOfPeople = 0;
    int number;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

    System.out.println("Enter a number or -1 to finish");
    number = input.nextInt();
    while (number !=-1) {

        total = total + number;
        numberOfPeople++;
        System.out.println("Enter a number or -1 to finish");
        number = input.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("The average is: " + total / numberOfPeople);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my other solution using ArrayList. Hope it can help you :)

```
    int number = 0;
    int  total = 0;
    int numberOfPeople = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number or -1 to finish");
    number = input.nextInt();
       while (number !=-1 ) {

        total = total + number;
        numberOfPeople++;
        if(numberOfPeople == 5){
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a number or -1 to finish");
        number = input.nextInt();
        myList.add(number);

    }
       System.out.println("The average is: "+ total/numberOfPeople);
```